# Declaring types for vue-router meta

Tags: typescript, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

In my `router.ts` I added some meta properties that have the 'getter' then I'm interested in using when that component loads.

```js
{
    path: "attachments",
    name: "AdminJobsAttachments",
    meta: {
        navbarName: "Attachments",
        getter: "Jobs/getJob", // <- this
    },
    component: () =>
        import("@/views/common/Attachments.vue"),
},
```

When the component loads I retrieve that information like so:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
        const store = useStore();
        const getter = computed(() => route.meta.getter);
        const routeParam = ref(route.params.id);
        const model = computed(() =>
            store.getters[getter.value](routeParam.value)
        );

        return {}
    }
})
```

However, Typescript gives me the following error:

> Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.

I'm quite new to Typescript so this maybe something I am overlooking but I'm not able to figure out how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#typescript)

> It is possible to type the meta field by extending the `RouteMeta` interface:

```
// typings.d.ts or router.ts
import 'vue-router'

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    // must be declared by every route
    navbarName: string
    // is optional - does not have to be on every route
    getter?: string
  }
}
```

Note that as `getter` is declared as optional property, you are required to test it's presence before using it...

Comment: Could you please be more explicit on where I would place this code? I'm asking because putting it in the router or component file doesn't seem to help.

Comment: `// typings.d.ts or router.ts`  ...be sure to not leave out the `import 'vue-router'` line